# malloc issue with struct of containing an array of strings

Tags: c++, string, malloc

I've read the other posts about this issue. When I change the top line:

```
typedef char Key_type;
```

to

```
typedef string Key_type;
```

I get a memory access error at `p->key[1] = x;`

```
typedef char Key_type; // change this to string and it breaks
typedef struct node_tag{
    int count;
    Key_type key[maxSize + 1];
    struct node_tag *branch[maxSize + 1];
}Node_type;

Node_type *Insert(Key_type newkey, Node_type *root)
{
    Key_type x; /* node to be reinserted as new root    */
    Node_type *xr;  /* subtree on right of x        */
    Node_type *p;   /* pointer for temporary use        */
    Bool pushup; /* Has the height of the tree increased? */

    pushup = PushDown(newkey, root, &x, &xr);
    if (pushup) {   /* Tree grows in height.*/
        /* Make a new root: */
        p = (Node_type *)malloc(sizeof(Node_type));
        p->count = 1;
        p->key[1] = x; // memory access error
        p->branch[0] = root;
        p->branch[1] = xr;
        return p;
    }
    return root;
}
```

What small modification can be made to eliminate the memory access error?

Comment: Hint: `malloc` allocates memory but doesn't run constructors.

Comment: Malloc and C++ are not happy bedfellows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call the constructor for your string. Also, get in the habit of writing C++ and not C:

```
typedef string Key_type;
struct Node_type{ // don't need to do typedef ...
    int count;
    Key_type key[maxSize + 1];
    Node_type *branch[maxSize + 1];
};

Node_type *Insert(Key_type newkey, Node_type *root)
{
    Key_type x; /* node to be reinserted as new root    */
    Node_type *xr;  /* subtree on right of x        */
    Node_type *p;   /* pointer for temporary use        */
    Bool pushup; /* Has the height of the tree increased? */

    pushup = PushDown(newkey, root, &x, &xr);
    if (pushup) {   /* Tree grows in height.*/
        /* Make a new root: */
        p = new Node_type;
        p->count = 1;
        p->key[1] = x; // memory access error
        p->branch[0] = root;
        p->branch[1] = xr;
        return p;
    }
    return root;
}
```

If you don't provide a ctor for the struct the compiler will create one for you (as well as a dtor).

Answer (score 1):

classes may be created using the operator new, not malloc. When using string member, you need to do

```
p = new Node_type();
```

instead of

```
p = (Node_type *)malloc(sizeof(Node_type));
```

The operator new initializes internal memory of the string. The malloc function, not.